# Sum Range If Cell in Row Equals Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet to calculate costs for a software project. We're using an Agile approach which means we do chunks of work at a time (called a "phase"). I've put costs together broken down into four areas (UX, Design, Frontend, Backend) and I'd like to get a sum for the first phase.

My rows are made up of merged cells to help formatting. The screenshot below, shows a few rows that end up building the entire spreadsheet. I'm trying to write a formula that gets the sum of the component i.e. Header and Footer are both phase 1, so I want to add them together. But, Forms is phase two, so I want to leave that cost out.

To make the example a little more clear, the formula for phase 1 should equal £560 (the sum of the Header and Footer totals - both phase 1, indicated in the C column). Phase 2 should equal £1067.50 because the only component in phase 2 is "Forms".

[image: Spreadsheet Layout]

Comment: Is it always 4 rows for each reference?

Comment: @SQLTemp It is indeed, all "rows"/references follow the exact format shown above.

Comment: And column H exists?  If so a simple SUMIF will do, `=SUMIF(C:C,1,H:H)`

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner - that's done the trick! Feel free to put in an answer and I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Column H is merged identical to column C, the values are in the same row.  A simple SUMIF will suffice:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,1,H:H)
```

With merged cells the data is only in the upper left cell of the merged area.  In your example C3,H3;C7,H7;C11,H11.  The other cells are blank.  SUMIFS will compare row by row and find the matches in C and return the value in H to be summed.